# .NET embedded LDAP server

Tags: c#, ldap

Is there any embedded LDAP server that could be used in integration tests written in c#?
I know some java solutions, but can't find anything for .NET.

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: Have you thought of trying Microsoft Fakes or Pose framework? while not exactly full integration tests, these would be good UTs to protect code from unexpected modification

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Pose. But it's not what I'm looking for. I need something real for integration tests. Something like UnboundID LDAP for java, where I can start server, configure it in test, add data and query.

Comment: @Michal did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: I've used docker container with open ldap for this purposes. https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap

Answer (score 1):

I like to use docker images for testing. Somebody else has already done the work of setting up the environment.  All you have to do is set a few configuration variables and run docker-compose up.
Here is one such environment:
[docker-test-openldap][1]
Install Docker, Create a docker compose yml file with the settings for this project.  Then from the same directory, run:

Docker-compose up

This starts a virtual service exposing the ports in the way you configured in the file.  Docker does all the work of downloading and managing the services for you so all you have to focus on is the yml file.  Here is a sample yml file from the repo.

```
version: '2'

services:
    ldap:
        container_name: ldap
        # use the image tag to pull directly from the repo
        # image: rroemhild/test-openldap
        environment:
            LDAP_FORCE_STARTTLS: "true"
            LDAP_DOMAIN: "customdomain.com"
            LDAP_BASEDN: "dc=customdomain,dc=com"
            LDAP_ORGANISATION: "Custom Domain, Inc."
            LDAP_BINDDN: "cn=admin,dc=customdomain,dc=com"
        # use build tag to use the local repo
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        ports:
            - '10389:10389'
            - '10636:10636'
#        volumes:
#            - data_volume:/var/lib/ldap/
#
#volumes:
#    data_volume:
```

You can see the ports are configurable. In this sample, port 10389 is mapped to the same port, but if you're using that port, you can change it.
Uncommit the image line to download the image automatically (then commit the build section), and uncommit the volume section if you need the image to hold persistent data, (not be reset every time you start the image)
[1]: https://github.com/rroemhild/docker-test-openldap

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30728488)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution:
https://github.com/flamencist/ldap4net

Cross platform port of OpenLdap Client library (https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldap)
and Windows Ldap (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_ldap/) to DotNet Core